# Oracle TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_DATE, 'd') in where has ORA-01847 Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

`AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '7'`

`AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '1'`

They has trouble.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) AS WEEK
     , OM.* 
FROM ORDER_MASTER OM
WHERE YMD BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'
  AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '7' -- this occur error
  AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '1' -- this occur error too.
ORDER
   BY YMD
```

This query occur ORA-01847 Error.

But `AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '7'` and `AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '1'` removed, it work.

When I checked data, `ORD_YMD` data is normal.

What is the diffrent between having `AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '7'` and `AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '1'` and not having it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `ORA-01847` exception, that means you have data in your table where `ymd` is an invalid date.

The query may work without those two filters because the invalid date is not within the range `YMD BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'` so that filter is excluding the invalid date. When you include the additional filters using `TO_DATE` then the SQL engine can chose to process the filters in any order and is opting to use `TO_DATE` on all the rows before applying the `BETWEEN` filter and, since there is an invalid date, is generating the exception.

You need to fix your data so that your dates are valid; once you do that then the query works.

> What is the different between having `AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '7'` and `AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd')) <> '1'` and not having it?

*Note: you do not need the outermost `TO_CHAR`.*

Having it will filter to find days that, for your territory settings, are not the 7th or the 1st day of the week. Not having it will include all days of the week.

For example, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE order_master (ymd) AS
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2023-08-01' + LEVEL, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;
```

Then:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') AS WEEK,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'day') AS day,
       OM.* 
FROM   ORDER_MASTER OM
WHERE  YMD BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'
ORDER BY YMD;
```

Outputs all the days:

| WEEK | DAY | YMD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | wednesday | 20230802 |
| 7 | thursday | 20230803 |
| 1 | friday | 20230804 |
| 2 | saturday | 20230805 |
| 3 | sunday | 20230806 |
| 4 | monday | 20230807 |
| 5 | tuesday | 20230808 |

But with the filters:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'America';

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') AS WEEK,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'day') AS day,
       OM.* 
FROM   ORDER_MASTER OM
WHERE  YMD BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'
AND    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') <> '7'
AND    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') <> '1'
ORDER BY YMD;
```

Outputs:

| WEEK | DAY | YMD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | wednesday | 20230802 |
| 5 | thursday | 20230803 |
| 6 | friday | 20230804 |
| 2 | monday | 20230807 |
| 3 | tuesday | 20230808 |

Excluding Saturday and Sunday.

If you run the same query for different territories:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Germany';

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') AS WEEK,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'day') AS day,
       OM.* 
FROM   ORDER_MASTER OM
WHERE  YMD BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'
AND    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') <> '7'
AND    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') <> '1'
ORDER BY YMD;
```

Outputs:

| WEEK | DAY | YMD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | wednesday | 20230802 |
| 4 | thursday | 20230803 |
| 5 | friday | 20230804 |
| 6 | saturday | 20230805 |
| 2 | tuesday | 20230808 |

Excluding Sunday and Monday (as in Europe, the week is considered to start on Monday so Monday would be day 1 and Sunday, day 7).

and:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Bangladesh';

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') AS WEEK,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'day') AS day,
       OM.* 
FROM   ORDER_MASTER OM
WHERE  YMD BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'
AND    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') <> '7'
AND    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OM.YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'd') <> '1'
ORDER BY YMD;
```

Outputs:

| WEEK | DAY | YMD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | wednesday | 20230802 |
| 2 | saturday | 20230805 |
| 3 | sunday | 20230806 |
| 4 | monday | 20230807 |
| 5 | tuesday | 20230808 |

Excluding Thursday and Friday (as in Bangladesh, the week starts on Friday)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0DsDxF1G)

Comment: Your right. Wrong `YMD` in all data, not `BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'`, but it occur error. thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to store dates as strings. Don't do that. Why? Because it causes errors like the one you got:

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

It means that `ymd` column contains value(s) that aren't valid dates, e.g. 202308**55** (no 55th of any month) or 202302**29** (not 29th of February 2023) etc.

---

As of your code: why all those conversions, if all you care about are the last two **characters** in a string that represents a date value? Use `substr` function instead.

Also, format model you used in `select` column list suggests that you want to extract *day*, not *week*.

```
  SELECT om.*, 
         SUBSTR (ymd, -2) AS day     --> day, not week!
    FROM order_master om
   WHERE     ymd BETWEEN '20230726' AND '20230905'
         AND SUBSTR (ymd, -2) NOT IN ('01', '07')
ORDER BY ymd;
```

Comment: I want extract week, because I except sunday and saturday. If data is wrong, why error not occurs when two conditon not in where?

Comment: Note that you can't always get what you want (especially not with invalid data). What value do you expect out of e.g. today's date, 6th of September 2023 (in your table, YMD = 20230906, I presume)?